# How do I use FTSearchSorted to filter a view in XPages?

Tags: full-text-search, xpages

I'm working on my Excel exporting using Apache POI. I want to be able to include a query string to limit the exported contents, but I either end up getting 0 documents or getting a couple of documents.

When I get a couple of document, it's unclear if the view object is actually modified. It still responds to getEntryCount with 13 documents, but exports just 2 and doesn't print the columnValues for those two. If I don't use the search, it exports the entire view flawlessly.

The server-side javascript has these few relevant lines.

```
function createWorkbookStreamWithLabels(workbookName,sheetName,fieldList,dbName,viewName,colLabels,totalLabels,queryString){
...a bunch of other code to get a handle to the view...

postValidationError(control,"Entries: " + view.getEntryCount());
var docCount = view.FTSearchSorted(queryString);
postValidationError(control,"Query: " + queryString);
postValidationError(control,"Query count: " + docCount);
if ( docCount == 0) return;

...code that walks the view and prints the contents...
}
```

My 0 hit queries include:

```
FIELD lastname CONTAINS e
```

and

```
[state] CONTAINS V
```

The one that gets two hits is simple:

```
VA
```

The view is sorted and now the database is full-text indexed. The column containing State is now sorted and click to sort, ascending.

Just for reference, here's the function that displays my status messages.

```
function postValidationError(control, msg) {
    if ((typeof msg) != "string")
            return;
    var msgObj = new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage(javax.faces.application.FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msg, msg);
    facesContext.addMessage(control.getClientId(facesContext), msgObj);
    control.setValid(false);
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Update: the problem with my search queries is solved, but my code also seems to have a terrific tendency to crash HTTP or the server.

Comment: I would start to check the FullText query. The way I normally do that is to open the view in the Notes client and enter the query there. You might need to add a wildcard to the query, e.g. `[state]=v*`

Comment: Precisely correct. I've not done much full-text searching, so didn't realize that was my mistake. Thanks again, Mark. That takes care of the searches, now I have to see if I can figure out the failure to export the columnValues.